# Using gcloud console for Google App Engine causes a Runtime error from metrics

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to use the gcloud console through the browser. When I clone my repository and start the dev server, I get a runtime error from metrics:

```
$ dev_appserver.py $PWD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1041, in <module>
    main()
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1037, in main
   dev_server.stop()
 File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 845, in stop
   metrics.GetMetricsLogger().Stop()
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/metrics.py", line 117, in Stop
  total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm not calling the metrics module directly or otherwise using it. How can I disable it in the console or in the code so that I can start my app ok?

It runs ok locally via the SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dev_appserver.py` metrics were recently added in the Cloud SDK version 144.0.0 for users who have opted-in during [SDK installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes). The Cloud SDK installation provided in the Cloud console at https://console.cloud.google.com is also opted in to using these metrics.

In response to this post, we've added some additional logic to prevent this misleading error message in the future. This update will appear in one of the upcoming releases.

Comment: If this bug affects you, the easiest solution is:

`gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true`

Comment: thanks @sterne, helped me out after an hour of debugging :)

Comment: i went:
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false
then got another error :(

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by resolving an issue in my app.yaml file, one of my routes wasn't specified correctly.

Fixing that route with a leading slash, and escaping the dot within the route regex, seemed to resolve the error too:

```
diff --git a/app.yaml b/app.yaml
index 8a165a0..39c68b3 100644
--- a/app.yaml
+++ b/app.yaml
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ handlers:
 - url: /ui
   static_dir: ui

-- url: robots.txt
+- url: /robots\.txt$
   static_files: robots.txt
   upload: robots.txt
```

Comment: Similar story here, but I had forgotten my `upload` property

Comment: I got the same error because I wrote `script controller/user.app` instead of `script controller.user.app`