# GAE Error When Trying To Run App via Dispatch File

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to run my app using the dispatch file like so:

```
  $ dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app1/app.yaml app2/app.yaml
```

gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1041, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1037, in main
    dev_server.stop()
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 845, in stop
    metrics.GetMetricsLogger().Stop()
  File "/Users/usera/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/metrics.py", line 117, in Stop
    total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm using the latest gcloud installation from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/). Each service/module (e.g. app1/app2 in the command above) is written in go.

Content of my dispatch file:

```
application: my-app

– url: “*/app2/*”
module: app2

– url: “*/app1/*”
module: app1
```

My python version is 2.7 of course. Any ideas?

Comment: `self._start_time` is NOne

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gcloud console for Google App Engine causes a Runtime error from metrics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495197/using-gcloud-console-for-google-app-engine-causes-a-runtime-error-from-metrics)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem too, and I believe the issue is dev_appserver requires a default module to route requests which don't match any dispatch rules.

I was able to define a default module by removing the `service` attribute from the `app.yaml` for my default module, and removing the dispatch rule for that module.

In your case, remove the `service` attribute from `app1/app.yaml` (if present), and remove the dispatch rule which points to app1 in `dispatch.yaml`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unless the app already has a `default` module as well, in which case that module's `.yaml` file needs to be added to the `dev_appserver.py` cmdline (I'd place it the 1st one after the dispatch file).

Comment: @DanCornilescu How do you define a "default" module? I don't see a property for that in [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref)

Comment: By leaving its name undefined (as you mentioned in your answer) or by explicitly naming it as such: `service: default` or `module: default`

Comment: The `default` module is always required, not only for the `dispatch.yaml` file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360790/why-do-i-need-to-deploy-a-default-app-before-i-can-deploy-multiple-services-in

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have a default module setup and no service attribute in none of my apps

Comment: Awesome, thanks @DanCornilescu. @orcaman, to solve your issue, add the `service: app2` attribute to `app2/app.yaml` and remove the dispatch rule for `app1` in your `dispatch.yaml`. That should do the trick!