# getting Type error while running dev_appserver.py

Tags: git, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dev-appserver

I wanted to deploy my repository to google cloud platform thus had successfully cloned the same using cloud shell but while running dev_appserver.py it gave a type error, below is the error:

---

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~$ AIDIR=~/src/ai-fiance-162601/apiai-finance-2017-03-30-23-43
natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~$ git clone https://github.com/Neeraj-Natu/NLP_Finance.git $AIDIR
Cloning into '/home/natu_neeraj/src/ai-fiance-162601/apiai-finance-2017-03-30-23-43'...
remote: Counting objects: 847, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (742/742), done.
remote: Total 847 (delta 95), reused 819 (delta 85), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (847/847), 2.04 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (95/95), done.
natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~$ cd $AIDIR
natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~/src/ai-fiance-162601/apiai-finance-2017-03-  30-23-43$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~/src/ai-fiance-162601/apiai-finance-2017-03-    30-23-43$ dev_appserver.py $PWD
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 101, in <module>
_run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2    .py", line 1041, in <module>
main()
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1037, in main
dev_server.stop()
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 845, in stop
metrics.GetMetricsLogger().Stop()
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/metrics.py",     line 117, in Stop
total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

### natu_neeraj@ai-finance-162601:~/src/ai-fiance-162601/apiai-finance-2017-03-        30-23-43$

Can anyone please help me what i am doing wrong?

i use python 2.7.13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gcloud console for Google App Engine causes a Runtime error from metrics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495197/using-gcloud-console-for-google-app-engine-causes-a-runtime-error-from-metrics)

Comment: Tried with opening just one browser and in it just one tab for the cloud platform and tried to redeploy the project again, but still the same error occurred.

Comment: Does the same app code work on your local devserver? If so - do you launch the server using the same cmdline?

Comment: Did you try `gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true`?